# Angular (click) function takes two clicks to fire assigned Typescript function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a Typescript function that I have assigned to (click) in my HTML. I have to click it twice in order to fire off the function. If I don't pass in any parameters, the function will work with one click.

The Typescript:

```
public postActionPath: PostActionPath = {
    system: '',
    application: '',
    service: '',
    host: '',
    action: '',
    potentialActions: []
  };


setPostActionPath(system, application, service, host, potentialActions) {
    this.postActionPath.system = system;
    this.postActionPath.application = application;
    this.postActionPath.service = service;
    this.postActionPath.host = host;
    this.postActionPath.action = '';
    this.postActionPath.potentialActions = potentialActions;
  }
```

The HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="setPostActionPath(system.system, application.application, status.service, status.host, service.actions)">
Take Action
</button>
```

I was expecting the (click) to work on one click.

Comment: Smells like there's nothing wrong with the method, but you have problem with ChangeDetection. Hard to tell without full component code (and even this could be not enough, as all the parents are involved in CD)

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

This is angular and you should probably use Observables, the async pipe and ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, but that poses some changedetection challenges in itself so I won't cover that here (OnPush is not a fix for changedetection problems, more like a culprit for them, but it does have huge performance advantages)

To fix this quick and dirty, you probably do this:

```
 constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
 // and this in the last line of setPostActionPath
 this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Or you can re-assign the object:

```
   setPostActionPath(system, application, service, host, potentialActions) {
      this.postActionPath = {
            ...this.postActionPath,
            {
               system, application, service, host, action: '', potentialActions,
            }

      }
```

}

That's my 2 cents with this info